# Python3 version in shell downgraded after installing lower version of python3 on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I installed python via the official installer here https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/

Currently, I have these 2 in my applications folder [image]

However, in my terminal, when I type python3 -V, I get 3.11

Prior to installing python 3.11, my python3 was pointing to python 3.12.2. How do I get it to point to 3.12.2 again? I don't want to set up pyenv, I just want the default python3 version to be 3.12.2

I've tried setting an alias for python3 but that didn't resolve my issue

Comment: The program that is run when you type `python` is determined by your PATH. Your shell looks at each directory in your PATH till it finds `python` then runs that one. Check your PATH with `echo $PATH`. Change your PATH in your login script. Put the directory with Python 3.12 before the directory with Python 3.11 if you want to use 3.12. Don't uses aliases. Start a new terminal if you change your PATH in your login script.